# LINQ to XML: How to clone nodes while retaining annotations?

Tags: .net, xml, linq

Try this:

```
var doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\any.xml", LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
var doc2 = new XDocument(doc1);
```

doc2 no longer has any line number information. Digging in with Reflector, I can see that when the nodes are cloned from doc1 to doc2 this does not preserve the annotations on the XObject base type, which includes the line number information accessible via `IXmlLineInfo`. Nor does it retain the BaseUri, which I also need.

Any ideas how I can clone the document while preserving line numbers? I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikechampion/archive/2006/09/10/748408.aspx) but it doesn't preserve BaseUri and is a bit of a hack.

Comment: I have gotten around this in my particular case by keeping a reference to the original XDocument which is never modified and just used to look up line numbers and BaseUris.

Answer (score 1):

This retains the LineInfo at least (I didn't try the BaseUri as I didn't need it):

```
using (var xmlReader = doc1 .CreateReader())
   doc2 = XDocument.Load(xmlReader, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save it into a memory stream and then reload it into a new instance of `XDocument`.

Comment: That would still lose the original BaseUri and line number information, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame, but yes, of course it would. Could you get away with wrapping the new instance with something that can hold the original BaseUri?